# How to set minSize in Bootstrap Validator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jqbootstrapvalidation

I'm trying to figure out how to set the minSize for a file upload using Bootstrap Validator plugin.

Given the following code, I can set the maxSize `maxSize`, but not `minSize`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#test').bootstrapValidator({
            live: 'enabled',
            fields: {
                fileupload: {
                    validators: {
                        file: {
                            extension: 'png',
                            type: 'image/png',
                            maxSize: 1024 * 1024,
                            message: 'The selected file is not valid, or the size is not large enough!'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Is there a way to set it for minSize?

Comment: I'm using this for a file upload though, so it needs to be file size. String length would be for text input length.

Comment: Yeah tired and misread your question, I have deleted the comment to keep the thread clean.

Comment: @Matt did you see my answer below ?

Comment: minSize and maxSize validation rules are not working in BootstrapValidator v0.5.2, built on 2014-09-25 4:01:07 PM. :(

Comment: Sorry, my fault :/ it works as said @Arkni

Answer (score 2):

as [nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/blob/master/demo/file.html)

---

```
validators: {
    file: {
        extension: 'png',
        type: 'image/png',
        minSize: 1024*1024,
        message: 'Please choose a png file with a size more than 1M.'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest code of [BootstrapValidator](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator) (v0.5.2-dev), the **minSize** option was implemented.

So you can do the following :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').bootstrapValidator({
        live: 'enabled',
        fields: {
            fileupload: {
                validators: {
                    file: {
                        extension: 'png',
                        type: 'image/png',
                        minSize: 100*1024, // for example 100 KO 
                        maxSize: 1024 * 1024,
                        message: 'The selected file is not valid, or the size is not large enough!'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Refrences :

- The latest code of [File validator](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/blob/master/src/js/validator/file.js#L12).
- Pull request [#803](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/pull/803).
- File validator example : [demo/file.html](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/blob/master/demo/file.html).

Comment: minSize and maxSize validation rules are not working in BootstrapValidator v0.5.2, built on 2014-09-25 4:01:07 PM. :(

Comment: Hi @PasinduJayanath, It's still working for me, see https://jsfiddle.net/Arkni/6gcpL53n/. Maybe you misconfigured the validator. Please recheck your configuration.

Comment: Yep, I tried that. it works! :)  thanks.. :D My fault. :/ sorry.. :(