# Bootstrap Validator not working on File Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form field that should only accept a .jpg or .png image at a certain file size. The validation doesn't seem to be working(tested with invalid file types). This is what I have so far, so what is it I'm missing? I should work like it does here http://bootstrapvalidator.com/validators/file/

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/933yvfmh/3/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form id="fileupload">
        <div class="row top">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 logo">Image Cropper</div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel crop">
                    <div class="well">
                        <input type="file" mulitple name="fileupload" class="btn btn-default form-control" id="file" />
                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="reset">Reset</button>
                        <input id="renderButton" type="button" value="Render final image" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="container" class="well"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 render">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="result_container" class="result thumbnail"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

//HIDE CONTROLS UNTIL IMAGE SELECTED//
$("#reset, #renderButton, .render").hide();
$("#file").click(function () {
   $("#reset, #renderButton").show();
});
//ONLY SHOW RENDERED VIEW WHEN RENDER BUTTON CLICKED//
$("#renderButton").click(function () {
    $(".render").fadeIn("slow").animate({
        right: '50px'
    });
    $(".render, #result_container").show();
})
//RESET RENDER VIEW//
$("#reset").click(function () {
    $(".imgly-container").empty();
});


$('#fileupload').bootstrapValidator({
    live: 'enabled',
    fields: {
        fileupload: {
            validators: {
                file: {
                    extension: 'jpg, png',
                    type: 'image/jpg, image/png',
                    minSize: 1024 * 1024,
                    message: 'The selected file is not valid, or the size is not large enough!'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: in your fiddle you're using the **v0.4.5** version and the **minSize** is available only from the **v0.5.2** version.

Comment: I think you didn't read properly the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649867/how-to-set-minsize-in-bootstrap-validator

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the spaces in extension and type

```
extension: 'jpg,png',
type: 'image/jpg,image/png',
```

See: http://formvalidation.io/validators/file/

Best regards,
thosimo

Comment: I have since changed the way I am handling input validation, to simply not allow other file types to be selected in the file chooser with `accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/jpeg"`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

> notEmpty: {
>    message: 'This field can not be empty.' 
>   }

So your code should be

```
validators: {
     notEmpty: {
         message: 'This field can not be empty.' 
     },

     file: {
         extension: 'jpg, png',
         type: 'image/jpg, image/png',
         minSize: 1024 * 1024,
         message: 'The selected file is not valid, or the size is not large enough!'
         }},
```

Hope this work.